# Parsing RSS feed URLs

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss, nsxmlparser

After wiring up a RSS feed to an iOS app, data populates the UITableView with titular entries for each cell but the links to these entries return 404 at the URL's homepage. Anything without .rss returns 404 at the URL's homepage after clicking on a cell.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.themostunrealbeats.com/?feed=rss2"];
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [parser parse];
    }
```

Is there a way to allow URLs not ending in .rss to return their data?

Comment: Doesn't this seem like an issue with the web server and not your code or your app?

Comment: Doesn't it have to do with the way the feed links are parsed? If a feed link ends in .rss, then after clicking on a cell the URL returns data. If a feed link does not end in .rss, then after clicking on a cell the URL returns a 404. I tried numerous links. Is there a way to parse links properly for iOS apps?